# Load 1 bean from @configuration in SpringBoot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing, configuration, autowired

PIDClient has HttpClient (Java 11) as a dependency in its constructor. I want to autowire this so I created an @Configuration annotated class named SpringConfiguration. I got it working with the code below.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {PIDClient.class, SpringConfiguration.class})
public class PIDClientTest {
```

My issue with this is, now it loads all the beans in SpringConfiguration while I only need HttpClient bean. I tried the code below but that gave me a `No qualifying bean of type 'java.net.http.HttpClient'`.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {PIDClient.class, HttpClient.class})
public class PIDClientTest {
```

Here's a screenshot of the projects' directory structure in case it's needed with the relevant classes open.
[image]

Is there a better way?

Comment: So you are creating a unit test or integration test? Do you need the real implementation of HttpClient?

Comment: It's a unit test of a class with a dependency on HttpClient. Actually, I don't need a real implementation of the class and indeed, I can use a mock instead. The code is now working with an @MockBean annotation on the HttpClient field and without loading the configuration.